# Can we deduce that $x$ is a common divisor of $y$, $z$ and $u$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let us consider the following relations between integers:

$x$ divides $yw$

$x$ divides $zt$

$x$ divides $uq$

and

$x$ is not a common divisor of $w$, $t$ and $q$. Here $w$, $t$ and $q$ are composite.

Can we deduce that $x$ is a common divisor of $y$, $z$ and $u$? If not, can we add some conditions to guarantee this property?

**PS**: We can consider $x$ as the product of three primes. We assume that those primes are factors of $w$, $t$, and $q$ respectively.

Comment: Let $x = p_1 p_2 p_3$. What if $p_1 p_2$ divides $w$, $p_2p_3$ divides $t$, $p_1 p_3$ divides $q$? Then $x$ is not the gcd of $w, \ t, \ q$ and it is not necessary that $x$ should divide $y, \ z, \ u$ either

Comment: @P.J. Can we find some conditions to conclude the result in the question.

Comment: If $w$, $t$ and $q$ are primes which do not divide $x$

Comment: @P.J. This condition is impossible in my case since those numbers are composite.

Comment: Or they can be composite, but their prime factors do not divide $x$

Comment: @P.J. For the second time, this is also impossible! $x$ contain some prime from the other numbers.

Comment: Can you add more context to your question?

Comment: @P.J. Ok done. see the question.

Comment: If y, z, u are multiples of x, I think

Comment: @P.J. Yes. This is my idea. but I have no proof.

Comment: if y, z, u are multiples of x, then of course $x$ divides the gcd. What is there to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, take $x$ to be any product of three primes $abc$ and set $y=a,w=bc$ and $z=b,t=ac$, etc.)

I don't see a natural extra condition that forces this (other than $x$ being coprime to each of $w,t,q$ in which case it is not a very interesting statement). For example, you can certainly have $w,t,q$ being pairwise coprime without it working, by taking $x=abc,y=ab,z=bc,u=ac,w=cd,t=ae,q=bf$ where $a$ to $f$ are distinct primes.

Comment: If $x$ being coprime to each of $w,t,q$, then how one can prove that $x$ divide the other numbers.

Comment: @Safwane if $x\mid yw$ and $x$ is coprime to $w$ then it divides $y$. One way to show this is by induction on the number of primes dividing $x$. If $p$ is a prime factor of $x$ then $p\mid yw$ and $p\not\mid w$ so $p\mid y$. Then set $x'=x/p$ and $y'=y/p$. Now $x'\mid y'w$ and $x'$ is coprime to $w$...